# Mysterious problem on setting up Reverse Prime (NVIDIA Optimus offloading through OutputSink) for an HDMI external monitor

Tags: nvidia, video, hdmi, optimus

I just recently decided to try Prime (NVIDIA offloading applications to its gpu, while system using integrated gpu, in my case Intel HD630) on my Slackware-current laptop, and soon I discovered that I couldn't use my HDMI port while running on integrated intel gpu since that port was connected to the nvidia gpu card, which was now enabled only on demand. The solution I soon found out to be the new Reverse Prime, but I can't seem to make it work because **strange things are happening** under the hood. I'm looking for help trying to figure out what is happening.

At first, Prime apparently worked fine on laptop screen (I first used it to run a GPU intensive application, it worked as expected, full performance). You run the application you want to run on NVIDIA gpu prefixing it with some environment variables. But later when I tried `__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia glxinfo` for a test I noticed it was not working specifically with glxinfo, giving this error:

> ```
> name of display: :0
> X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
>   Major opcode of failed request:  151 (GLX)
>   Minor opcode of failed request:  24 (X_GLXCreateNewContext)
>   Value in failed request:  0x0
>   Serial number of failed request:  39
>   Current serial number in output stream:  4
> ```

And then i tried `nvidia-settings --verbose` with and without the environment variables, also getting an error:

> ```
> WARNING: NV-CONTROL extension not found on this Display.
> ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
>
> ERROR: Unable to assign attribute SyncToVBlank specified on line 22 of ........
> ERROR: Unable to assign attribute FSAA specified on line 24 of ........
>         (repeat similar message to several other video settings previously saved on nvidia-settings-rc file)
> ERROR: Unable to assign attribute SynchronousPaletteUpdates specified on
>        line 38 of configuration file
>        '/[home path, redacted]/.nvidia-settings-rc' (no Display
>        connection).
> ```

Running `nvidia-smi` works normally giving accurate information on nvidia gpu (weirdly with no need to run with the environment variables). I checked `glxinfo` without nvidia variables, wondering if my primary gpu was really Intel by now, and it was indeed the integrated intel gpu. Then I run `xrandr --listproviders` and got this:

> ```
> Providers: number : 2
> Provider 0: id: 0x43 cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
> Provider 1: id: 0xca cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 4 outputs: 1 associated providers: 1 name:modesetting
> ```

Note that it detects both gpu but the second one (*Provider 1*) should be named NVIDIA-G0 but it was also set to *modesetting*, like *Provider 0* (the intel igpu). I then configured *xorg.conf* for a quick temporary test, to start X with NVIDIA gpu as primary, and run `xrandr --listproviders`. By doing that *Provider 0*, now corresponding to the NVIDIA, was correctly identified with the name NVIDIA-G0, and *Provider 1* with *modesetting*. I reverted *xorg.conf* to the Prime/Optimus configuration again (i.e. intel as the active gpu). Running `lsmod | grep -i nvidia` indicates that nvidia drivers are loaded and *nouveau* drivers are blocked as expected due to *modprobe.d* configurations:

> ```
> nvidia_uvm           1155072  0
> nvidia_drm             65536  1
> nvidia_modeset       1232896  2 nvidia_drm
> nvidia              34177024  19 nvidia_uvm,nvidia_modeset
> drm_kms_helper        266240  2 nvidia_drm,i915
> drm                   610304  15 drm_kms_helper,nvidia_drm,i915
> i2c_core               94208  12 i2c_designware_platform,videodev,i2c_hid,i2c_designware_core,drm_kms_helper,i2c_algo_bit,nvidia,i2c_smbus,i2c_i801,i915,psmouse,drm
> ```

Plugging the HDMI cable was correctly identified (still no signal though), and according to `xrandr --props`, HDMI-1-1 source lists as **Prime Syncronization** enabled:

> ```
> PRIME Synchronization: 1 
>         supported: 0, 1
> link-status: Good 
>         supported: Good, Bad
> CONNECTOR_ID: 74 
>         supported: 74
> non-desktop: 0 
>         range: (0, 1)
> ```

I was curious of what was happening here so I tried going ahead and test hdmi output with the [Reverse PRIME tutorial on Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PRIME#Reverse_PRIME) since everything else was functioning as it should with Prime setup on laptop screen (despite not knowing why `glxinfo` and `nvidia-settings` failed), but as the name of the providers were wrong I decided use its reference number so I run `xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 0 1`, which resulted in a kinda similar error of that from `glxinfo`:

> ```
> X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
>   Major opcode of failed request:  139 (RANDR)
>   Minor opcode of failed request:  35 (RRSetProviderOutputSource)
>   Value in failed request:  0xca
>   Serial number of failed request:  16
>   Current serial number in output stream:  17
> ```

And tried to go ahead anyway trying to find a clue, `xrandr --output HDMI-1-1 --auto --above eDP-1` (eDP-1 being the built-in screen of the laptop) resulted in:

> xrandr: Configure crtc 3 failed

No apparent error on Xorg.0.log but something on *dmesg* during boot process, which seemingly didn't prevented the nvidia driver from working:

> ```
> [drm:nv_drm_dumb_map_offset [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to lookup gem object for mapping: 0x00000006
> [drm:nv_drm_dumb_map_offset [nvidia_drm]] *ERROR* [nvidia-drm] [GPU ID 0x00000100] Failed to lookup gem object for mapping: 0x00000007
> ```

And a warning that NVIDIA taints the kernel:

> ```
> nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
> Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
> ```

**EDIT 1:** After suspecting that Prime offloading with variables was only working on laptop native screen with command-line programs, with no graphical interface, I tried running some lutris game and indeed got the same error from *glxinfo*. So maybe this has to do with trying to connect to a display?

## I have no idea where to go from here. Do you have any idea?

---

### System information:

- Laptop Acer Nitro 5, i7 7th gen, NVIDIA 1050
- Kernel 5.10.19 patched with fsync from TKG, Slackware-current 64bits with alienbob multilib
- NVIDIA driver 460.56, CUDA release 11.2, V11.2.67 Build cuda_11.2.r11.2/compiler.29373293_0
- Xorg Server 1.20.10
- */etc/X11/xorg.conf* (I'm still not used to .d snippets model): https://pastebin.com/0d13wDHY
- Had this *90-intel.conf* on *xorg.conf.d* though, intended to force intel DRI3:

> ```
> Section "OutputClass"
>     Identifier "Force DRI 3"
>     MatchDriver "modesetting"
>     Option "DRI" "3"
> EndSection
> ```

- Xorg.0.log (removed keyboard, cam, bluetooth irrelevant lines): https://pastebin.com/s0Ebu2AY
- *dmesg* with some sensitive data redacted: https://pastebin.com/w0qWzxD9
- NVIDIA driver set to modeset (via conf file on *modprobe.d* `options nvidia-drm modeset=1`)

Comment: Some similar, but not identical, problems I found elsewhere

- https://forum.manjaro.org/t/unable-to-launch-nvidia-settings/24027

- https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/lswyd5/installing_nvidia_drivers_on_f33_from_rpmfusion/

- https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/prime-render-offload-badvalue-integer-parameter-out-of-range-for-operation-when-trying-to-use-nvidia-gpu/109807

- https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/centos-7-unable-to-run-nvidia-settings/80048

Comment: Hey, have you ever found a solution to this? I've run into the exact same problem and I opened a topic on the NVidia forums [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/failed-to-lookup-gem-object-for-mapping/186526).

Comment: Sorry, i couldn't find a solution and eventually put that aside, though if new ideas show up i will certainly try and post here!